# How to validate bower.json?

Tags: json, bower

I have an error with my bower.json file.

A google has turned up that this is quite common, often because of a non-printable character (due to using an editor that uses such characters).

Is there a way to validate the file locally from the cli?

As an FYI, my error is as follows:

```
bower meltingpot#*          EMALFORMED Failed to read /tmp/james/bower/meltingpot-5659-xBMHsL/bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token ]
```

The contents of my bower.json file are as follows:

```
{
  "name": "meltingpot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jamesjenner/meltingpot",
  "authors": [
    "james-jenner <james.jenner@########.com>"
  ],
  "description": "HTML based application, websockets for comms and node.js for backend",
  "keywords": [
    "application",
    "websocket",
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "application.js",
    "bower_components",
    "comms.js",
    "node_modules",
    "*.json",
    "panelHandler.js",
    "shared/panel.js",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

While I'm happy if someone can point out the cause of the problem, the real question is how do I validate the bower.json file to detect and identify any errors. Preference would be that the line is provided where the error occurs.

:edit:

I created a quick script to read in the bower file, parse the data via JSON and then stringify the result. From experience if the json file contained malformed json then I would have received an exception. So it looks like the problem isn't with the format of the file, but with the contents.

Code I used to test the file:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data;

try {
  data = fs.readFileSync('bower.json');
} catch (e) {
  if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
    // ENOENT is file not found, that is okay, just means no records
  } else {
    // unknown error, lets throw
    throw e;
  }
}

var json = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, ' '));
```

:edit:

I've now tested using the `bower-json` package (thanks to [jayeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409068/jayeff)), and still validates as okay. Code used is as follows:

```
var bowerJson = require('bower-json');

// Can also be used by simply calling bowerJson()
bowerJson.read('./bower.json', function (err, json) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('There was an error reading the file');
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
    }

    console.log('JSON: ', json);

    try {
      bowerJson.validate(json);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('There was an error validating the object');
        console.error(err.message);
    }
});
```

:edit:

Just to be clear on the solution (provided by [drorb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097634/drorb) below), the problem was that I had created a tag, noticed the extra comma and then fixed the comma just by committing the change. As far as bower was concerned, it was taking the latest release/tag, so was ignoring the fix in my commit.

In addition, while in git you can remove a version via `git -d <tag>`, bower appears to take the release, not the latest tag (there are complications with how github uses releases). In my case I deleted 0.1.0, added 0.0.1 and bower register ignored 0.0.1. I was forced to create a 0.1.1 tag (after committing the changes in the bower.json file) and then I was able to register.

I've now discovered that you can delete the releases from github, via the website interface (refer [Editing and Deleting Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-and-deleting-releases/)). I was able to tidy up my releases, update the `package.json` and then push the release I wanted via `git tag <tag> -a -m "<desc>"` and `git push --tags`. Now `bower info <mypackage>` displays the correct information.

I've added the above, as this was not discussed when I looked through other stackoverflow posts that have this problem. I hope the above makes clear the issue of tags and commits with bower, trying to register and how to tidy up any mistakes.

I also recommend reading [Creating and Maintaining your own Bower Package](http://bob.yexley.net/creating-and-maintaining-your-own-bower-package/).

Comment: Perhaps update the title and the body of this question so that it doesn't erroneously show up in google searches for people trying to validate their bower.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the bower.json you posted which I assume is the on you have in the master branch.
The issue is the version of the file found in the [0.1.0 tag](https://github.com/jamesjenner/meltingpot/blob/0.1.0/bower.json) - there is aמ unnecessary comma in the ignore list:

```
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "Gruntfile.js",
    "application.js",
    "bower_components",
    "comms.js",
    "node_modules",
    "package.json",
    "panelHandler.js",
    "shared/panel.js",
    "test",
    "tests", << issue is here
  ]
```

Running your test code against this file produces the correct error message:

```
undefined:27
  ]
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\work\js\meltingpot\test.js:16:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: Ahh, you have to be joking! I saw other people make the same mistake and thought I register would use the latest commit. Does the register command only use the latest tag, not the latest commit? Ahh found the answer at http://bob.yexley.net/creating-and-maintaining-your-own-bower-package/ in the maintenance section. The version in the bower.json is what is used against the tag for the git repository. thanks drorb! I feel like such a dofus O.o

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your bower.json complies with the specs with the help of [bower-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-json#readfile-options-callback).

The [code for bower-json](https://github.com/bower/bower/tree/master/packages/bower-json) is in the main bower repository.

Comment: Thanks jeyeff, I had just stumbled upon that by reading through the bower code. Just tried it and no luck. The JSON validates fine. The error must be coming from within the bower logic. :(

Comment: the link is dead.